# How to fix garbled text with using WriteFile on a pipe?

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I have a Win32 application that I'm making, and it sends a string from one process to another via a named pipe. However, the process that calls ReadFile on the pipe gets the string with some garbled data in it. It returns the number of bytes written correctly, but the last 8 characters or so of the string are garbled.

Here is the code for creating the pipe, and writing to it:

```
myPipe = CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe", PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, PIPE_NOWAIT, 10, 512, 512, 10, NULL);
TCHAR title[128];
GetWindowText(foundHwnd, title, 128);
wstring windowTitle(title);
vector<wstring> splitVec;
boost::split(splitVec, windowTitle, boost::algorithm::is_any_of(wstring(L"|")));
WriteFile(myPipe, splitVec[0].c_str(), splitVec[0].size(), &wrote, NULL);
```

And here is the code that reads it:

```
if (WaitNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe", 5000) == 0) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Unable to wait for pipe", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}

myPipe = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (myPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Unable to open pipe", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}
    // Other code here...
    TCHAR buf[512];
    DWORD read;
    success = ReadFile(myPipe, buf, 512, &read, NULL);
    if (read > 0)
        MessageBox(NULL, buf, L"Got Data", MB_OK);
```

When MessageBox is shown, the end of the string is garbled and I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key here is to make sure that your strings are null terminated and that you send the termination character as well.  You shouldn't have to send the entire buffer if the communications is synchronous or if you set it up in `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`.  ReadFile will return when either the specified number of bytes has been read or a write operation completes on the other end of the pipe. I believe that the "garbled" text is really garbage in the read buffer on the client side of the pipe and because you are not transmitting the string termination character, it is including this in the text sent to the message box.  Either clear your read buffer before sending or send the string termination character with the message and I think it will work without the overhead of sending a full buffer.

Here is [sample client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365592(VS.85).aspx) from MSDN.  Note how the client sends exactly the number of characters in the message **+ 1** (including the termination character) and receives into a fixed buffer of size 512.  If you look at a [server example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365588(VS.85).aspx), you'll see the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I was now having a problem with half the string being sent. I needed the (lstrlen(..)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR), as shown in the example.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Multibyte characters.  I didn't even think of that.

Comment: good catch, I updated my answer fixing it with *sizeof(TCHAR)

Answer (score 2):

Some observations on the code you posted:

- You need to either 1) explicitly send the null terminated byte, or 2) append one to the data you read.
- Since you are reading 512 bytes, you should also be sending exactly 512 bytes.
- You can send variable length strings instead by first sending the size of the string, and then sending that many bytes.  That way when you read the data you will know how many bytes to read for the actual string.
- The problem with what you did will be seen as soon as you send 2 things over the pipe, and you read past what you really want in the first read.
- If you are only sending 1 thing over the pipe, you can keep your code, but send size() + 1 when you write to the pipe.
- ReadFile / WriteFile were meant to send binary data, not necessarily strings.  So you can make a function called ReadString and WriteString that implements my suggestion about reading/writing first the size then the actual string.

Try something like this:

Here is the code for creating the pipe, and writing to it:

```
myPipe = CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe", PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, PIPE_NOWAIT, 10, 512, 512, 10, NULL);
TCHAR title[128];
GetWindowText(foundHwnd, title, 128);
WriteFile(myPipe, title, 128*sizeof(TCHAR), &wrote, NULL);//<---In this case we are sending a null terminated string buffer.
```

And here is the code that reads it:

```
if (WaitNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe", 5000) == 0) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Unable to wait for pipe", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}

myPipe = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (myPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Unable to open pipe", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}
    // Other code here...
    TCHAR buf[128];
    DWORD read;
    success = ReadFile(myPipe, buf, 128*sizeof(TCHAR), &read, NULL);
    if (read > 0)
        MessageBox(NULL, buf, L"Got Data", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize pipes needed the length to be exact. Thought they would do it that stuff for me. It is working now!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with "garbage in the pipe" when writing a generic function to read stdout from any process executed at the command prompt.  Therefore, I couldn't alter what was being written to the pipe (as is commonly suggested), I could only alter the read side.  So, I "cheated".

If the pipe data didn't end in a null terminator, I replaced the last char with one!  It seemed to work for me.  I saw this work perfectly where there were nulls and where there were not at the end of my data chunks.

I worried that I might lose a critical last char (and it's possible that you might!), but for my immediate purposes, that didn't happen.  You might consider adding a null rather than replacing the end under some circumstances...

Here's code snippit:

```
const unsigned int MAX_PIPE_PEEKS = 100;
DWORD bytesInPipe = 0;
unsigned int pipePeeks=0;
while( (bytesInPipe==0) && (pipePeeks < MAX_PIPE_PEEKS) )
{
    bSuccess = PeekNamedPipe( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, NULL, 0, NULL, 
                              &bytesInPipe, NULL );
    if( !bSuccess ) return bSuccess;  // Bail on critical failure                
    ++pipePeeks;
}
if( bytesInPipe > 0 )
{
    // Read the data written to the pipe (and implicitly clear it)
    DWORD dwRead; 
    CHAR *pipeContents = new CHAR[ bytesInPipe ];    
    bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, pipeContents, 
                         bytesInPipe, &dwRead, NULL );
    if( !bSuccess || dwRead == 0  )  return FALSE;  // Bail on critical failure              

    // "Cheat" - eliminate garbage at the end of the pipe
    if( pipeContents[ bytesInPipe ] != '\0' )
        pipeContents[ bytesInPipe ] = '\0';
}
```

UPDATE:

After further testing, I found that this is not quite reliable (shocking, huh?).  I think I'm on the right track though for a relatively simple solution. Any ideas for getting this quick patch to work?